# Tune Parameters in Gradient Boosting Reggression with cross validation, sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

Suppose X_train is in the shape of (751, 411), and Y_train is in the shape of (751L, ). I want to use cross validation using grid search to find the best parameters of GBR. I used the following code, but could not success.

```
 from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV 
 param_grid={'n_estimators':[100,500], 
            'learning_rate': [0.1,0.05,0.02],
            'max_depth':[4], 
            'min_samples_leaf':[3], 
            'max_features':[1.0] } 
n_jobs=4
def GradientBooster(param_grid, n_jobs):
    estimator = GradientBoostingRegressor() 
    classifier = GridSearchCV(estimator=estimator, cv=5, param_grid=param_grid, 
    n_jobs=n_jobs)
    classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print classifier.best_estimator_ 
return cv, classifier.best_estimator_ 
cv,best_est=GradientBooster(param_grid, n_jobs)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
     51         from pandas.core.config import get_option
     52 
     53         encoding = get_option("display.encoding")
---> 54         return self.__unicode__().encode(encoding, 'replace')
        self.__unicode__.encode = undefined
        encoding = 'cp0'
     55 
     56     def __repr__(self):
     57         """
     58         Return a string representation for a particular object.

LookupError: unknown encoding: cp0
```

Then, I want to use these parameters to predict `X_test` using predict function.

I also have the same problem with the following code:

```
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'max_depth': [80, 90, 100, 110],
    'max_features': [2, 3],
    'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5],
    'min_samples_split': [8, 10, 12],
    'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300, 1000]
}

rf = RandomForestRegressor()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid = param_grid, 
                          cv = 3, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2)
grid_search.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Comment: The above error appeared. Just I am looking to use GBR with cross validation, following by a prediction function on the test data.

Comment: The error comes with the following line: `cv,best_est=GradientBooster(param_grid, n_jobs)` The error is too long, 43 pages in a doc word.

Comment: Aha, could you add a small sample data set, that would help us to reproduce this error?

Comment: `cv` is not defined in the code you provided

Comment: @pythonic833 Is it different with `cv=5`?

Comment: Please see the edition. I have the same error with the new code as well.

Comment: `cv` is only defined within the function  `GridSearchCV`. Your edited code looks fine for me. What is the error message? Do  `X_train ` and  `Y_train` have the same dimensions?

Comment: I have mentioned the shape of them. Note that I have categorical variables which are fine for both RF and GBR. Maybe it has a problem with gridsearch?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example on a test data set

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X,y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'max_depth': [80, 90, 100, 110],
    'max_features': [2, 3],
    'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5],
    'min_samples_split': [8, 10, 12],
    'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300, 1000]
}

rf = RandomForestRegressor()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid = param_grid, 
                          cv = 3, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2)
grid_search.fit(X, y)
```

most likely there is a problem with your data.